# htaccess - parsing php into html

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I recently played with a `.htaccess` file to make one server to parse PHP files. Yesterday I uploaded the same `.htaccess` file and tried to test a PHP file. But something went wrong: visiting my page the browser offers to download the the html page rather then viewing the page!

On the server the filenames end in `.html`.

I added the following to my `.htaccess` file:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

I tried to find the htaccess file, but once uploaded it just disappears from the root dir.
I tried to upload other scripts I've found browsing. I even tried to search for some problem on a hosting forum. Nothing helped.
Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
```

OR

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
```

And remove other overriding handlers for `application/x-httpd-php` after above code.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem, and if he doesn't use .php or .htm extension then there is no need to...

Comment: Thanks! but how to remove if I can't see any htacces folder or file eather. See @Cyber-Guard Design's answer. May I try just to re-upload a .htaccess file with this codes?

Comment: And yes, I removed the test php i've tried to explore, now I just need to undo changes. Seems like mission impossible

Comment: Please correct your spelling of `tryed` its `tried`, It should be ok in `.htaccess`

Comment: The AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html HELPED! But only if i write www.roko.x10.mx/index.html , otherwise it won't open again

Comment: solved. I applied and made all the possible changes and 'rewrites' as you and @Cyber-Guard suggested me. Now after a day the page opens nicely even from root. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Right, firstly things first, what host do you use?

Also what ftp client you are using? Some by default won't display files starting with `.` such as `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd`, that's why it may appear that you didn't upload it. Also it might be that you don't have the rights to upload in the very root directory, try to go one directory up.

Also from my experience, hosts won't allow you to modify headers via `.htaccess` this way, because the `allowoverride` directive is off; instead have a look at url rewrites (via `mod_rewrite`), which allow you to do the same thing without modifying headers.

Your rewrite `.htaccess` file might look something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(\w+)\.html$ $1.php [NC]
```

(Not tested though)
Using a rewrite will also mean that your files will in fact maintain the php extension, however they will be access via urls that include `.html` extension.

Comment: strange... after I applyed all the changes, and waited a day... now everything works fine! THANKS for the suggestions and help!